# Cucumber: rails dynamic find not working in paths.rb

Tags: ruby-on-rails, find, cucumber

I am working on rails with rspec, rspec-rails, cucumber and webrat.
I am trying to learn BDD and testing in general.
I have a cucumber scenario like this:

```
  Scenario: Questions List
    Given quiz titled "Pearl Jam" has questions named "Corduroy, Dissident"
    When I go to the experiment page for quiz titled "Pearl Jam"
    Then I should see "Corduroy"
    And I should see "Dissident"
```

I have alrady added step 1, where I create and save a quiz correctly (I tested through puts).
Now I am working on step 2. I am adding a new path in paths.rb

```
when /^the experiment page for quiz titled "(.*)"$/i 
  new_quiz_experiment_path(Quiz.find_by_title($1))
```

For some reason `find_by_title` does not work. I get this error message:

```
new_quiz_experiment_url failed to generate from {:quiz_id=>nil, :action=>"new", :controller=>"experiments"}, expected: {:action=>"new", :controller=>"experiments"}, diff: {:quiz_id=>nil} (ActionController::RoutingError)
```

I am sure the record is there, and correctly saved; if I insert

```
puts Quiz.find(1).title
```

I get "Pearl Jam". Looks like `find_by` is not working, which is quite weird since the cucumber generated file contains this example:

```
  #   when /^(.*)'s profile page$/i
  #     user_profile_path(User.find_by_login($1))
```

I also tried a simpler find first with conditions, it doesn't work either.

Any idea?

Thanks in advance,
Davide

Comment: Try using "find_by_title!" with the exclamation mark at the end. It might give a more descriptive error message.

Comment: Perfect tip. I got "Couldn't find Quiz with title = Pearl Jam"; following the hint I realised that I had parsed the previous step inconsistently, saving the name as "Pearl Jam" (WITH quotation marks); that explains why I didn't find the record. Thanks!

Comment: Also, I realise just now that you're Ryan of railcasts. This test cases where modelled after your cucumber introduction, so your tip have been quite appropriate and timely! Thanks again, also for the great railcasts job!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to ryanb's suggestion I was able to find the bug, which was in

```
Given quiz titled "Pearl Jam" has questions named "Corduroy, Dissident"
```

Basically I had parsed this step inconsisetntly; I had inserted the quotation marks in the 1st regex, so the tile got saved as

```
"Pearl Jam"
```

I guess I've lerned two things:

- Be careful with quotation marks in step definitions
- use method with the extra `!` for more expressive error messages.

Comment: Thank you!  This issue was plaguing me and I had the same problem.